# heroku logs --tail doesn't quit on ctrl-c (Ubuntu)

Tags: heroku, rvm, ubuntu-11.04

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04, rvm and Heroku.

When I'm doing this `heroku logs --tail`

Ctrl-C doesn't stop the process, contrary to the documentation.

Comment: This works fine for me on Ubuntu 12.04 and 11.10.  But I'm using the [Heroku Toolbelt](http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/linux/readme), not rvm.  Did you install the Toolbelt or the gem?

Comment: It works now, I guess it was fixed in the meantime. Closing the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: It seems not. Mac OS.

Answer (score 3):

**Try Ctrl-Break.** 
It fixed this problem on Windows for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try Ctrl-Z. It worked for me on Linux Mint.